# post route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have done everything the right way but my submit button doesnt do anything and I dont know why....

Here is my view

```
<form action="{{ route('importUser') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     @csrf
    add users via excell<input name="file" class="form-control" style="padding-bottom:3em; margin-bottom:3em" type="file">
    <div style="display:inline;">

     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="ارفع" >
</div>
</form>
```

Here is my controller

```
function importUser(Request $request)
 {

 #code...
 }
```

and my route

```
Route::POST('ImportUsersFile', 'ExcelUserController@importUser')->name('importUser')->middleware('Admin');
```

Apparently, the flow dont get in the function import user. I tried to dd into it but nothing happend!

Comment: what error u got?

Comment: Is there something in your laravel.log?

Comment: Is $request empty?

Comment: production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): No application encryption key has been specified. at D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\site\\Activity_Datawarehouse\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider.php:42)
[stacktrace]

Comment: It doesnt do anything when clicking the button though. The submit button is dummy

Comment: That is vital information. Can you please edit your question and paste it there? What's the value of `APP_KEY` in your `.env` file? Did you run `php artisan key:generate` ?

Comment: I cant tell if request is empty because the flow of the code doesnt get to importUser so when I dd over there nothing shows up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `url` intead of `route`

```
<form action="{{ url('ImportUsersFile') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
add users via excell<input name="file" class="form-control" style="padding-bottom:3em; margin-bottom:3em" type="file">
<div style="display:inline;">

 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="ارفع" >
</div>
</form>
```

And in your routes:

```
Route::post('ImportUsersFile', ['uses' => 'ExcelUserController@importUser', 'as' => 'importUser']);
```

Comment: can you try removing `@csrf` ? see my updated answer

Comment: may be  cache issue try to run  `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 3):

According to an error message you provided in a comment, try this:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Comment: What error do you get when generating the key? More details needed.

Comment: I didn't get errors. it says key generated successfully. I restarted the server and still nothing happend

Comment: Before using Laravel's encrypter, you must set a key option in your config/app.php configuration file: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/encryption